# Separate network with second router behind openmesh/cloudtrax site?

Tags: networking, routing, lan, subnet, vlan

My wife and I live on a "campus".  They have a CloudTrax (openmesh if I'm not confused) network.  I have been given authorized access to configuration settings.  I have a wired connection from a lan port on the main router "ROUTER1" (that is connected to the fiber internet connection) to a LinkSys WRT1900AC "ROUTER2".  I'm a CS major and have done some network config before, but this is stumping me.

How do I create a separate "isolated" network on ROUTER2.

Basically, according to what I can see on the ROUTER1 (CloudTrax) config pages, I (believe) I can do one of the following:

- Set up a separate LAN from one of the ROUTER1 physical ports.
- Set up a VLAN, which I'm honestly a little confused about.
- Give ROUTER2 a reserved IP address and try an finagle it.

### Environment Overview

- Fiber connection "modem" Gateway
- CloudTrax G200 (Model A64) (ROUTER1)
- About 7 (OM2Pv2) Wireless Access Points supporting 2 separate WiFi SSID's connecting close to 200 clients
- LinkSys WRT1900AC (ROUTER2) wired/connected to LAN port on ROUTER1
- LinkSys LGS105 5-port unmanaged switch connected to LAN port on ROUTER2

### Goal for the setup

- I'd like for us to be able to connect all our devices to ROUTER2's WiFi and LAN ports for internet access.
- Run my personal devices (servers, desktops, printers) (on ROUTER2's "network") so that I have access when off site, and so they can "talk" to each other.
- Keep ROUTER1's clients out of ROUTER2's network

#### What I've tried

- Before they moved to the CloudTrax, I was able to simply give my router (ROUTER2) a reserved IP address on (the old) ROUTER1 going from LAN port on ROUTER1 to WAN port on ROUTER2 and a separate subnet on ROUTER2.  I was able to communicate with my local server, set up a separate WiFi SSID, and connect all my stuff to the internet through ROUTER2.
- Right now, as a temporary fix for internet access, I've got the LAN port from ROUTER1 connected to a LAN port on ROUTER2 so it's acting like a switch.

### My Request

Simply put, help me take the shortest path around my backside to get to my elbow.  What settings to I need to adjust here.  Thank you in advance!

### Supporting Diagrams and Images

#### Network Diagram (Basic)

[image: Basi Network Diagram]

#### Images of Cloudtrax Settings Pages

[image: CloutTrax Setting 1]
[image: CloutTrax Setting 2]
[image: CloutTrax Setting 3]
[image: CloutTrax Setting 4]
[image: CloutTrax Setting 6]
[image: CloutTrax Setting 7]

Answer (score 0):

You can make a subnet from router2 but you won't be able to see router2 through router1 as it will be double natted.
You can use a vpn to bridge the connection but of course your network will be open to anyone.